# How to use feature scaling in multivariate time series data?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, standardized

I am trying to do classification on multivariate time series data. I want to perform feature scaling on this kind of data. Suppose the multivariate time series data looks like this:

```
F1                             F2                              F3                             
[1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0........]    [41.0 23.0 3.0 4.0.........]    [103.0 27.0 3.0 43.0.......]        
[331.0 2.0 3.0 4.0......]    [41.0 23.0 3.50 444.0......]    [1333.0 27.0 3.0 43.0......]
```

and so on,

How should I use the feature scaling here to bring all the features into same range?

Method 1: 
1. For each list in F1 calculate mean and standard deviation and standardize the data
2. Repeat the above step for all the list in all the features (F2, F3)

Method 2: 
1. Calculate the mean for of each list in F1, and then calculate the mean of mean of all the list, similarly calculate the std of each list and average over all the list in F1. Use this mean and standard deviation to standardize the feature F1
2. Repeat the above step for all the other features (F2, F3)

What is the correct approach to standardize this kind of data? Are the methods mentioned above correct?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score), the formula to standardize is:

```
z = (x-x')/S, where x is a point, x' is the sample mean and S is the stdev of the sample.
```

This means that `x'` should be the mean of all the lists in a column (for example F1), and `S` should be the stdev of all the lists in a column. Then this computation `z` should be applied to each point.

> What is the correct approach to standardize this kind of data? Are the methods mentioned above correct?

Method 1 is not a good approach, because the mean of list 1 will differ from the mean of list 2, and since they are part of the same sample the centering mean value should be the same. Method 2 is ok in the mean calculation, but I am not sure in the calculation of the stdev. Calculating the stdev of all the lists together is definitely correct.